# App doesn't ask location service permission WhenInUse when installation?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, location-services

I'm using google map in my app.I have set this in info.plist

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

and in my code(HomeScreen) i'm checking like this too:

```
 if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else{
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops !!" , message: "Location service seems to be disabled. Please enable from Settings -> Privacy ->LocationService.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But it doesn't ask permission when install the app for the first time. Any help would appriciate.

Comment: are you add 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>To be able to detect whether you are driving or not we need access to your location.</string>
</plist> in your .plist file ?

Comment: just set this code in your appdelegates.swift file

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Which code to add in AppDelagate??

Comment: Have a look into this Answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339284/3024579

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `Info.plist` key for accessing the location when the user is using the application (i.e. when it's in the foreground), but in your code, you're requesting permission whenever the application is running (i.e. always).

You need to decide which you want.  If you want to always be able to access the user's location, then change the `Info.plist` key.  If you want to access the user's location when your application is in the foreground, then change the permission request to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import CoreLocation
class AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       self.setupLocationManager()
       return true
}

func setupLocationManager(){

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

// Below method will provide you current location.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if currentCoordinate == nil {
        currentCoordinate = locations.last?.coordinate
        locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        print("locations = \(locationValue)")
        //currentCoordinate use this location Coordinate in your whole app.
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

// Below Mehtod will print error if not able to update location.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error")
}
```

If any query according my answer then tell me .

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan this is working then why give you down vote ?

Comment: sorry for that, how can i change it

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan just accept my answer . now its not roll back your down vote

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan if your problem solve then approve answer . Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 10 onward we need to give the location permissions in .plist file just like following[image]

and just check your app's location services enable or not in settings.Settings -> your app name -> Allow location Access. Never should not be selected.

Remove your app from device and reinstall app again then it should ask you the location permission.