# iOS 11 Location Permission in

Tags: ios, location, core-location, ios11

I have an app that need to use "always" as location update. However, it is found that after I have upgraded my device to iOS11, the app never ask me for permission.

and then when i go to Privacy > Location > 
the choices of "always" and "when in use" disappeared.

I have checked it is needed to add "Privacy – Location Always Usage Description" in the plist file. I have added, but it is still the same that it cannot track the location.

Anythings i have missed to update my code?

Comment: Have a look into this Answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339284/3024579

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For iOS 11, there's a new key `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`. Add this key to `Info.plist`.

Comment: Please check as this must the entry in plist :- NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription. There is a difference of "Use" in both the entry.

Comment: You will also need NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339284/3024579