# How to solve an Error related to NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription is required while it is present in plist file

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, info.plist

React native issues with geo location. I already have the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` key added in my `Info.plist` file. However, I still am getting below error in my react native project.

```
Cannot check or request permission without the required "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" entry in your app "Info.plist" file

-[RNPermissionsModule checkUsageDescriptionKeys:]
    RNPermissionsModule.mm:218
-[RNPermissionsModule handlerForPermission:]
-[RNPermissionsModule request:resolve:reject:]
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
```

I am not sure why am I getting above error and what is causing it to solve it. Thanks in advance for any help to resolve my issue.

Tried below solutions but none of them worked out.

[Location permission issue iOS 11 and iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398410/location-permission-issue-ios-11-and-ios-10)

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4166

Comment: This may solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415628/17771995

Comment: @Elevo I already followed that and mentioned in my post at the bottom.

Comment: `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription` instead of `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, they are different from each other.

Comment: Is it suppose to be the one I am already using according to that link. Still tried but no location fetched.